# Inverse of operator is not continuous in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $A:X\to X$ is an invertible bounded operator (injective,  surjective and continuous), then $A^{-1}$ is also bounded. Now can I have an example of an unbounded operator $A:D(A)\to X$ which is invertible but $A^{-1}:X\to D(A)$ is not bounded ?

Comment: By "invertible" you seem to mean "having a set-theoretic inverse"? Would you want something explicit, or does "any discontinuous bijection" meet the requirements?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I mean $A$ injective and surjective, but  $A^{-1}$ not continuous.

Comment: If $A\colon D(A) \to X$ is a linear bijection, then $A^{-1}$ is bounded (continuous) if and only if $A$ is closed. So you need to find bijections that aren't closed.

Comment: Thanks, this characterization is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the MathOverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5303/basis-of-linfinity to learn why it is consistent with ZF (without the axiom of choice) that there is no such operator.

Discontinuous everywhere defined operators can be defined using Hamel bases.  In particular, as Daniel Fischer points out, one can use a Hamel basis for $X$ to define discontinuous linear bijections $X\to X$ that answer your question.  All you really need is to define a discontinuous injective linear map $B$ on $X$, then take $A=B^{-1}$ on $B(X)=D(A)$.

Comment: That's interesting, I have just found maybe a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695980/about-linear-bijection-between-banach-spaces